# Ruby and Redis, threads not processing commands

Tags: ruby, multithreading, redis

I'm working with redis and ruby and attempting to issue a `blpop` within a thread, so that I can wait for an incoming item on a list.

The problem is that the code within the block for `blpop` never seems to get called. Here's the sample code that I'm running (ruby 1.9.3):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'redis'

def start_thread
  @thread = Thread.new do
    r = Redis.new
    r.blpop("test", 0) do |key, message|
      process_message(key, message)
    end
  end
  redis = Redis.new
  redis.rpush "test", "hello world"
end

def process_message(key, message)
  @message = "#{key} was sent #{message}"
end

start_thread
@thread.join
p @message
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'redis'

def start_thread
  @thread = Thread.new do
    r = Redis.new
    key, message = r.blpop(:test, 0)
    process_message(key, message)
  end
  redis = Redis.new
  redis.rpush :test, "hello world"
end

def process_message(key, message)
  @message = "#{key} was sent #{message}"
end

start_thread
@thread.join
p @message
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your code, and I still get `@message` returning `nil`. Also, I'm not sure why instance variables being declared inside methods is bad practice. Can you explain further?

Comment: Well ... cause a method is not an instance... I guess. I'm not an expert but I believe they should only be used with objects.
anyway, it seems to me that 'r' is empty so isn't blpop supposed to just wait until there is something to pop from the list?

Comment: That is correct, until right after the thread is created, when we do a `redis.rpush "test", "hello world"` right after it. It's getting to that part, at least, as I can see it come across when watching the redis console.

Comment: oh... here's the error. you are pushing to a diffrent list :)

Comment: `redis.rpush "test", "hello world"` where `"test"` is the key to push to.

Comment: I have modified my post. try that.

Comment: That still doesn't work. When Redis calls any blocking method, it blocks the entire instance of `Redis`, which is why in my `rpush` call, I have to instantiate another client, so I can push to the list. The redis server is still the same server, so it should respond, however, that's not happening on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17325/discussion-between-wedtm-and-ionut-hulub)